# How to set minimum confidence threshhold in Roboflows Inference API?

Tags: python, inference, roboflow

I have made a pretty good model with Roboflow and integrated it with python. I can't figure out how to set minimum confidence for the label to be shown. It works in HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you’ve implemented it in Python, you can use the Python package to set confidence threshold. https://docs.roboflow.com/python#methods

[highlighted code for setting confidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZbl4.jpg)

Example:

```
model.confidence = 30
```

Comment: Great! Thanks.  Also, can this also work with overlap?